# BigQuery - retrieving large number of rows with parallel pagination

Tags: google-bigquery

I need to retrieve large query results as fast as possible.
BQ allows sequential pagination, but it takes too much time (200K rows in 10 min).

Is it possible to do parallel pagination and if so, is the performance will actually improve in line with the number of the parallel requests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you probably know your query results are written to a table either anonymous or you can specify a name for it to be permanent.

Having that table you can use the `tabledata.list` API call to get the data from it. Under the optional params, you will see a `startIndex` parameter that you can set to whatever you want, and you can use in your pagination script.

You can run parallel API calls using different offsets that will speed your request. Make sure you are not hitting your badwith if the data is too big.

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/tabledata/list

Comment: Thanks.
I'm aware of that. Just trying to understand if there is more managed solution.
For example, one of the problems is i don't know the number of rows returned in one chunk from advance. If i choose to split the 200K into 10 requests of 20K, BQ still returns for each chunk only 8K rows at a time.
That means that eventually i do 10X3 requests to get all the data.

Is there a solution for that?

Comment: as far I know you need to script it, you maybe need to have two level of pagination